# "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None" when performing groupBy in pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has a `Booked date(String)` and `Movies count(Number)`. I need to get the sum of movies count based on the year in the Booked date. I first converted the Booked date to date format using UDF.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
import datetime as datetime

function date_string(str){
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str, '%m/%d/%Y')
}

func =  F.udf(date_string, DateType())
new_data = movies_data.withColumn('Date', func(F.col('Booked Date')))
```

The date is converted successfully. Then I grouped by Month using `groupby` and did `sum` function like:

```
new_data.groupBy(F.year('Date')).sum('Movies count').show()
```

I am getting this error:

`TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None`

I don't know how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:**
There is no `null` values in the data

Comment: Probably you want to print out the values, to see whether there is a `None` value in it. First step for your debugging

Comment: @Hari there is no None values

Comment: Is your `new_data.groupBy(F.year('Date)).sum('Movies count').show()` correct? Are there any syntax missing?

Comment: @Hari I guess its correct, BTW I used `new_data.select(F.year('Date')).distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()` to check whether it has `None`, but same error is coming

Comment: Yes, but one single quote `'` was missing in your question... that's why I was highlighting that

Comment: @Hari edited the question.

Comment: @Hari you are right. When i read the csv file, I am getting a whole row of `null` values but in my csv file, i dont have any null values. How is it possible?

Comment: It might be clearer if you can include the csv file in your question...